# Class Controller does not exist

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to make a CRUD (which was working fine in a simple blade) in a new template but it is not showing any page of crud and says not found. If I type: `php artisan route:list` then it says:

> Class App\Http\Controllers\PostsController does not exist

I'm following [this](http://www.webslesson.info/2019/03/step-by-step-crud-operation-in-laravel-58-with-file-upload.html) tutorial and my folder structure is https://ibb.co/db4WQ8R

**Controller**

```php
class CrudsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data = Post::latest()->paginate(5);

        return view('adminhome', compact('data'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|image'
        ]);

        $image = $request->file('image');

        $new_name = rand().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $image->move(public_path('images'), $new_name);
        $form_data = array(
            'name' => $request->name,
            'image' => $new_name
        );

        Crud::create($form_data);

        return redirect('post')->with('success', 'Data Added successfully.');
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/home', function () {
        if (Auth::user()->admin === 0) {
            return view('home');
        }

        return view('adminhome');
    });

    Route::resource('post', 'PostsController');
});
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller rename Cruds

```php
class PostsController extends Controller
  {
```

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/create this page still says: 404 not found these are routes https://ibb.co/W2N4RYC

Comment: as you can see route is post/create so url is 
127.0.0.1:8000/post/create